# Populate Dropbox on Webpage with Database Query

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am trying to populate a dropbox on my webpage using information that is stored in a database. When I load the page, the dropbox is empty and none of the information following the dropbox is displayed.

PHP FOR DROPBOX:

```
        <?php 
            $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT state_abbr, state_name FROM state_t ORDER BY state_name");
            echo '<select name="State">';
            while ($row = myssql_fetch_array($sql_query))
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['state_abbr'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

THE ENTIRE FORM ELEMENT HTML

```
<form
    action="http://webdev.spsu.edu/formtest.php"
    method="post">
    <div class="content">
    <table class="formTable">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="firstname">First Name:&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="First_Name" id="firstname" size="25" /></td>
            <td><label for="lastname">Last Name:&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="lastname" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="StreetAdd">Street Address:&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Street_Address" id="StreetAdd" size="25" /></td>
            <td>Select State:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    $sql_query = mysql_query("SELECT state_abbr, state_name FROM state_t ORDER BY state_name");
                    echo '<select name="State">';
                    while ($row = myssql_fetch_array($sql_query))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['state_abbr'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><label for="ZipCode">Zip Code:&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Zip_Code" id="ZipCode" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="appleorderquantity">Apple Quantity (pounds):&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Apple_Quantity" id="appleorderquantity" size="25" /></td>
            <td><label for="grapeorderquantity">Grape Quantity (pounds):&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Grape_Quantity" id="grapeorderquantity" size="25" /></td>
            <td><label for="strbryorderquantity">Strawberry Quantity (pounds):&nbsp;</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Strawberry_Quantity" id="strbryorderquantity" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Select Payment Method:<br /></td>
            <td>
                <label>MasterCard 
                    <input type="radio" name="Pref_Payment" id="pref_pay_Mcard" 
                        value="MasterCard" checked="checked" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>Visa 
                    <input type="radio" name="Pref_Payment" id="pref_pay_Visa" 
                        value="Visa" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>American Express
                    <input type="radio" name="Pref_Payment" id="pref_pay_AmEx" 
                        value="American Express" />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>Discover
                    <input type="radio" name="Pref_Payment" id="pref_pay_Disc" 
                        value="Discover" />
                </label></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
<div class="submitButton">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateOrder()" />
</div>
</form>
```

THIS IS WHAT IS DISPLAYING
[image]
THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DISPLAY
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
while ($row = myssql_fetch_array($sql_query))
```

It should be:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
```

It helps, while debugging, to see what errors are happening. You can add this line to an individual script to show all errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, it's time to stop using the deprecated mysql functions. Switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for MySQL only, or if you switch to [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can interface with MySQL and lots of other database types (MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc...).

Comment: That fixes the display issue, but the dropdown menu is still empty.

Comment: Do you connect to the database somewhere above the form code?  Is there a call to `mysql_connect` anywhere?

Comment: Ah, so are you using a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: yes. yes, i am. i added an `if (!$sql_query){die("Database error...");}` and it dies right after the dropdown menu so I'm guessing my php to connect to the database isn't correct....???

Comment: Yes, mysql functions only work with mysql databases. What you need is the whole set of [pg functions from the documentation](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php).

Comment: Thank you for the link to those functions. That fixed my problem!